# How to get license key for wacom signature sdk

Tags: android

I am trying to build a digital signature app that takes signature from the user and validates wheather the user is valid to proceed or not so iam trying to use wacom sdk for signature for android but it is asking for a license key from where do i get it?
Please if anyone know it share or suggest for other way for the approach.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.wacom.com/en-us/developer-dashboard/license-keys

You need to login into wacom developer dashboard and create license keys there. You can download a license file there and see the license key

Answer (score 0):

in the Wacom Signature SDK for Android documentation say:

> The Wacom Signature SDK for Android needs a valid license file, so if you don’t have one please
>   contant with your local vendor. Once you have a valid license you can initialise the Signature SDK for
>   Android with the following code (taking on account that you have the license file in your assets
>   folder):

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
try {
InputStream license = assetManager.open(LICENSE);
LicenseBootstrap.initLicense(getApplicationContext(),
LicenseBootstrap.readFully(license));
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

You must put this code  in the onCreate() function of the activity that use the Signature SDK.

You can get a trial license in the official page of Wacom. Also the App of example when you download the SDK contains a trial license that you can use.Then, for your app in pro, you must buy a license.

For more help: https://developer-docs.wacom.com/display/DevDocs/Signature+SDK+-+Android#app-switcher